# Winterbash 2014 is here - Do we participate?

Tags: discussion

[Winterbash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015, and the Community Team needs to know if we wish to participate or not. It is completely optional, but a fun little competition between all the participating sites during the Winter Holiday season.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “**I hate hats**” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, **all hats will go back into storage**.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Unless I see a lot of feedback *against* Freelancing.SE participating this year, I will put forth our application to go on with it. I will be submitting the answer on **November 30**.